# Javascript - Show name of next page when I hover over a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a previous and a next button to switch to the previous/next page. I want to show the name of the page (ist a Name of a customer) when I hover over the Buttons.

This is my HTML so far:

```
<a id="btn1"
  class="pager"
  href="<?php echo site_url("customer/". $prevId); ?>" 
  onmouseover="showPrevAcc()">
    <i class="icon icon-navigation-left left" aria-hidden="true"></i>Previous
</a>

<a id="btn2"
  class="pager"
  href="<?php echo site_url("customer/". $nextId); ?>" 
  onmouseover="showNextAcc()">
    Next<i class="icon icon-navigation-right right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

And this is my JS: (i need to replace the title text with variables)

```
function showNextAcc() {
  document.getElementById("btn1").title = "Next pages name";
}
function showPrevAcc() {
  document.getElementById("btn2").title = "Previous pages name";
}
```

Comment: You should come up with a minimal example of what you have tried so far on your own. Please note, SO ist not for getting your code written by us, but we like to help with a specific coding problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So what ? We have to write the code ? Just get the name of the next customer and pass it through parameters on mouseover.

Comment: I concur with my predecessors... More details, more code, a bit more effort please.

Comment: Where would you be taking the names from? Your question is very hard to answer unless you write more specifics.

Comment: It's just that i am not that good in Javascript. I don't want you to write my code but my question is how can I realize it **to show a specific text by hover over a button** and I thought that you maybe have a idea how i can realize that. In my code examples I tried to realize with changing the title.. but it doesn't work so maybe you have any idea??

Comment: Many elements have a `title` attribute that you can fill with information just for this reason; on hover, this will show a browser-typical tooltip. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp . Then the question still remains; where would you get the information?

Comment: The way how it works with title is good but maybe there is a pther way to solve this? maybe a jquery function or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can get next/prev. URL's location using some javascript methods.

```
var ex = document.getElementById("btn1").getAttribute("href").split("/");
var nextPage = ex[ ex.length - 1 ]; // here your next url
```

You can edit this code and make it better looks for showing to user.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly

```
<a id= "btn1" class="pager"  href="<?php echo site_url("customer/". $prevId); ?>" onmouseover="showPrevAcc()" title="<?php echo $pageName ?>"><i class="icon icon-navigation-left left" aria-hidden="true"></i>Previous</a>
```

You can use it by adding value to data set in JS way
var prevPage = ""

```
<a id= "btn1" class="pager"  href="<?php echo site_url("customer/". $prevId); ?>" onmouseover="showPrevAcc()" ><i class="icon icon-navigation-left left" aria-hidden="true"></i>Previous</a>

function prev(){
document.getElementById("btn1").title = prevPage
}
```

same can be used for next page name

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you're using Wordpress and for "name of the page" you're referring to the title, instead of Javascript you can use [get_next_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) and [get_previous_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) functions. Insert the returned value inside the `title` attribute.